# Display as grid from JSON in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

I am new in zf2. I have to display list of data from database and add, edit, delete operations using JSON. I am using this code to convert the data into JSON.

```
public function getList()
    {
    $results = $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll();
    $data = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
```

But I don't know how to display data from this JSON. I searched and didn't get any correct codes.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply decode the json and use the array in your view, I am not very clear about the scope of your question but from my understanding this is your model function which returns the data in json format, than you can decode the json and pass it to your view.

Comment: My doubt is where is to write the decode code? the above function returns JSON data like                                                          {"data":[{"id":"1","artist":"hvghvg","title":"cgfgfcc"},{"id":"2","artist":"ghjh","title":"hgg"},{"id":"3","artist":"snehajiju","title":"Sample"},{"id":"4","artist":"aaaaaaa","title":"aaaaaaa"}]} . How can I display this in a grid format? Any suggestions...please